# Asking for training during annual performance review

Tags: performance-reviews, training

I've joined the current company around 3 years ago. I have already been through 2 annual reviews and shortly the third is approaching.

On my last annual review, I've asked my supervisor for training that comes in line with what the business and I need.

There was a brief discussion about it during the annual review and after that nobody came back to me to tell me if it was approved or not, neither the manager nor the supervisor. Couple of months later, the then current manager leaves the company and a new one joins. On a brief one-2-one meeting with the new manager, I brought up the training issue again but 2 months later, I still haven't got a reply.

Please note that my annual reviews were always exceptional and one of the words used to describe my work was "Wow"! and they've never received negative feedback either for me or my work.

How should I point out that I feel bad that I never got a reply back and that they should really give me some training if they want to keep me.

Comment: Your delay in asking will likely work against you in that it will be seen as unimportant to you, i.e. if you cared about training so much, why did you wait a year to bring it up again?

Comment: The annual review is not the time for this.  After the review when you have an excellent is the time to leverage that to get training to keep you around.

Comment: @ChristopherEstep - If a manager said that to me, I would stand up, and walk out if their office with out a word, and start updating my resume.

Comment: @IDrinkandIKnowThings of course they wouldn't actually say it, I'm saying that could be the perception (and I think it might be somewhat valid).

Comment: "Because when I asked last year you said yes you would make sure it happened..." - Because I have been told that before

Comment: -ChristopherEstep I brought it up twice in 8 months and is a hot topic in our department, as we don't get any.I didn't feel like I needed to raise it again and again.

-JoeStrazzere Sadly we don't get regulars 1-2-1 as we are pretty busy. Also, I know it sounds like a threat but it's also the reality. When I joined I asked if they give training and they said yes, so far I've haven't received any.
If they don't want to provide training that's fine, but I didn't even get a reply which is what frustrates me, neither from supervisor nor the old and the new manager. Thanks for your comments.

Answer (score 2):

Be specific. What training do you want to take, when and where?'

Send you manager a short E-Mail requesting to approve that training. It should state what it costs, how long it takes and what the benefit for the work you are doing would be. If you do not get an answer, ask him every time you meet, if a decision has been made.